# NameError at /contacts uninitialized constant Contact::GoogleDrive

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working through the "RailsApps Project" Rails 4.1 tutorial right now, and am stuck on the spreadsheet connection section. When testing the application I get the following error:

```
NameError at /contacts
uninitialized constant Contact::GoogleDrive

update_spreadsheet () Users/sikendersingh/sideshow/learn-rails/app/models/contact.rb

  validates_presence_of :content
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}\z/i
  validates_length_of :content, :maximum => 500
  def update_spreadsheet
    connection = GoogleDrive.login(Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username, Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password
)
    ss = connection.spreadsheet_by_title('Learn-Rails-Example')
    if ss.nil?
      ss = connection.create_spreadsheet('Learn-Rails-Example')
    end
```

Here's the whole file:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_no_table

  column :name, :string
  column :email, :string
  column :content, :string

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_presence_of :content
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}\z/i
  validates_length_of :content, :maximum => 500

  def update_spreadsheet
    connection = GoogleDrive.login(Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username, Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password
)
    ss = connection.spreadsheet_by_title('Learn-Rails-Example')
    if ss.nil?
      ss = connection.create_spreadsheet('Learn-Rails-Example')
    end
    ws = ss.worksheets[0]
    last_row = 1 + ws.num_rows
    ws[last_row, 1] = Time.new
    ws[last_row, 2] = self.name
    ws[last_row, 3] = self.email
    ws[last_row, 4] = self.content
    ws.save
  end

end
```

Comment: Did you installed the gem 'google_drive'?

Comment: Yes all installed, here is my gem file:

ource 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.1'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'

# Rails defaults
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# learn-rails
gem 'activerecord-tableless'
gem 'foundation-rails'
gem 'gibbon'
gem 'google-drive'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'simple_form'
group :development do
 gem 'better_errors'
 gem 'quiet_assets'
 gem 'rails_layout'
end

Answer (score 0):

Found the problems:

1. accidentally installed the 'google-drive' gem instead of the 'google_drive' gem
2. in the secrets.yml file, I had the actual username, password, etc. instead of 'GMAIL_USERNAME' that would then go and look to my bashrc file.